# Play Console Crash cluster Showing new App Crash Report

Tags: android, crash, console, android-viewpager, androidimageslider

My Play console Crash Cluster Showing me same results Almost every day...... 
I made an app that contains mostly pictures using viewPagerAdapter(ImageSlider) & a listView. I have heard that this error is caused mainly by Pictures/ViewPagerAdapter.
Here is my link of both the apps- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.deb.nontefonte
&
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.deb.tintinbanglacomicsseries1
Here is my Cluster report-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue (Native Method)
at android.view.MotionEvent.getX (MotionEvent.java:2014)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent (ViewPager.java:2092)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2107)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2581)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2581)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2581)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2581)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2581)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2581)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2254)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:2607)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:1779)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent (Activity.java:2846)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:2568)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent (View.java:9003)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:4209)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:4072)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3646)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3763)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3820        
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3646)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:5910)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents (ViewRootImpl.java:5884)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:5855)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6000)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent (InputEventReceiver.java:185)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents (Native Method)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents (InputEventReceiver.java:176)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput (ViewRootImpl.java:5971)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:6023)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:767)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:580)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:548)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:753)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5930)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1405)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed ViewPager from my app and inserted a PDFView instead of that. Now it is doing same functionality but a little bigger in size. That's not a big issue to me.